# Error _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Tags: c++

I wrote a function that reads an `Image` (2-d array) from a file and returns it.

Calling it gave me a Block-Type error, which I could suppress by removing the destructor.
Where is my error? Do I even need a destructor?

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Pixel {
    float p;
};

class Image {
    int _x, _y;
    Pixel *pix;
public:
    Image(int x, int y) {
        pix = new Pixel[x * y];
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
    }
    ~Image() {
        delete[] pix;
        pix = NULL;
    }
    Image& operator= (const Image& param) {
        _x = param._x;
        _y = param._y;
        pix = new Pixel[_x*_y];
        pix = param.pix;
        return *this;
    }
    float getPixel(int i, int j) {
        return pix[(i-1) * _y + (j-1)].p;
    }
    void setPixel(int i,int j, Pixel val) {
        pix[(i-1) * _y + j-1].p = val.p;
    }
    Pixel **GetData() {
        Pixel **a=0;
        a = new Pixel*[_x];
        for (int i = 0; i < _x; i++) {
            a[i] = new Pixel[_y];
            for (int j = 0; j < _y; j++)
                a[i][j] = pix[i*_y + j];
        }
        return a;
    }
};

Image ReadFromFile(string a) {
    FILE * pFile;
    const char * c = a.c_str();
    Pixel pix,**tval;
    int n,m;
    pFile=fopen(c,"r");
    fscanf(pFile, "%i %i", &n, &m);
    Image img(n, m);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
            fscanf(pFile, "%f", &pix.p);
            img.setPixel(i, j, pix);
        }
    fclose(pFile);
    return img;
}

int main(){
    // Example Usage
    Image img(10, 10);
    Image img2(3, 3);
    Pixel val[10][10], **tval;
    for (int row = 1; row <= 10; row++)
        for (int col = 1; col <= 10; col++) {
            val[row-1][col-1].p = 2*row + col;
            img.setPixel(row, col, val[row-1][col-1]);
        }

    for (int row = 1; row <= 10; row++) {
        for (int col = 1; col <= 10; col++)
            cout << img.getPixel(row,col) << ' ';
        cout << '\n';
    }
    cout << '\n';
    tval = img.GetData();
    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
            cout << tval[row][col].p << ' ';
        cout << '\n';
    }
    string a;
    a = "C:/programs/misha/out.txt";
    img2 = ReadFromFile(a);
    cout << '\n';
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
            cout << img2.getPixel(row+1, col+1) << ' ';
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: `Image& operator=` is incorrect.  You allocate memory them immediately reassign that pointer which leaks memory and doesn't fix the potential double delete problem.  You need to copy the data from the other image into the memory you allocated.  You might also consider making all of your indices zero based.  The way you have it now is just prone to mistakes.